# Python turn certificate verification off

Tags: python, ssl-certificate

I need to disable certificate verification in a Python script. My script works if I use "verify=False" in the request, e.g.:
`result = requests.get('https://google.com', verify=False)`

I would like to use a parameter to enable/disable verification. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import requests
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--cert-verify', dest='cert_verify', help="Turn verification on/off")
args = parser.parse_args()

result = requests.get('https://google.com', verify=args.cert_verify)
print(result)
```

I am getting this error in the result:

```
./verify.py --cert-verify 'False'

requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

It looks like "False" value is ignored and script is looking for CA/path. How to fix this error?

Comment: Don't pass in 'False'?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `action="store_true"` i.e.

```
parser.add_argument('--cert-verify', dest='cert_verify', help="Turn verification on", action="store_true")
```

and then use it following way

```
./verify.py --cert-verify
```

If you want to know more read [Argparse Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html)

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. Is there any way to pass True/False as a value for the parameter (i.e. "./verify.py --cert-verify False")?

Comment: @IHeilig if you want to use like `./verify.py --cert-verify 'False'` then do not use any action, but be aware that you will get `False` *string* as `args.cert_verify`. You need to find way to convert it to *boolean* which would work for all your use cases